# Dual space of $l_p$ is $l_q$ norm equality

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading a proof that says we can idetetify $l_p^*$ with $l_q$ by the dual space action that associates an element $\eta \in l_q$ with the functional $\Phi_\eta$ given by $\Phi_\eta(\xi)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\xi_n}{\eta_n}$. In the proof they show that $\|\Phi_{\eta}\|=\|\eta\|$ which is true. However I am wondering if it is nessecary to show this or if we just need $\|\Phi_{\eta}\| \leq \|\eta\|$ which shows that the functional is bounded. I think it is nice that the norms actuallay are equal as that makes it more naturally too understand how $l_p^*$ and $l_q$ are "the same". However I also think that all we need is to show that the dual space action is continous surjective and injective (but I suspect I am missunderstanidng something here). So my question is, do we need that the norms are equal to say that $l_p^*=l_q$ (and why?). And is this a general thing for dual space associations?

Comment: It is necessary to prove that $\Phi^{-1}$ is continuous as well (a continuous, bijective map may not be an *isomorphism*), so you would need to prove that $$\|\Phi_\xi^{-1}\|\leqslant\|\xi\|$$ for all $\xi\in l^*_p$, which is equivalent, for a surjective map, to $$\|\eta\|\leqslant\|\Phi_\eta\|$$for all $\eta\in l_q$

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $\ell^q$ is topologically isomorphic to $(\ell^p)’$ for $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, i.e. there exists a bounded bijective linear map with bounded inverse $T : \ell^q \rightarrow (\ell^p)’$ (the one given by the Riesz representation theorem) it suffices to show that $T$ is bounded, indeed the following theorem holds:

Bounded inverse theorem:
Let $E$,$F$ be Banach spaces and let $T : E \rightarrow F$ be a bounded bijective linear map, then the inverse is bounded.

However the correspondence between $\ell^q$ and $(\ell^p)’$ given by $T$ is more than a topological isomorphism, it in fact an isometric isomorphism and you need to prove both the inequalities to obtain $||T|| = 1$. This correspondence is a very special case which arises in the context of $L^p(X,\mu)$ spaces and in a very similar way it holds in every Hilbert space, but it does not hold in a general Banach space.